# C++ Vectors with Array Elements?

Tags: c++

I am doing a project in my class that requires the program to stores teams into a vector. So I would have something like this:

```
string bballteam; 
vector<string> teamVector;
```

and then I want the user to input team names. So I can just prompt

```
cin >> bballTeam; 
teamVector.push_back(bballTeam);
```

to store the user input into the vector. However, I would like for the user input to be an array so that I can store players (like a roster). What are some ways I can implement this?
I acknowledge that you can't have arrays in a vector.

Comment: But you can have objects of classes in vectors, and those objects can hold arrays (or even other vectors).

Comment: *I acknowledge that you can't have arrays in a vector.* `std::vector<std::array<string, roster_size>>` is valid. But `roster_size` must be compile-time variable. https://godbolt.org/z/afKfKn1PP

Comment: Would vector of vectors work for you?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Vectors of vectors won't work. I need it to be a vector and a array.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is the following:

If you have many different attributes for one Object, then a `struct` or `class` must be used. If you have for example a "Player", then you would put the attributes of "Player" in a `struct`. Like this:

```
struct Player {
    std::string firstName{};
    std::string name {};
    unsigned int age{};
    double score{};
};
```

Here you have one **Type** with many attributes or properties.

If you need many "Objects" of same **Type**, then you would store those in an "array" type, like a C-Style array, or an `std::array`, or, if you need some variable size, a `std::vector`.

So, again

- Many attributes of different **Type** will be stored in a `struct`
- Many obejects with the same **Type** will be stored in n array.

Of course all these structures or arrays can be nested. You may have an array of `struct` or a `struct` containing arrays.

This depends on how you want to abstract the reality. It is about "relations".

For the input: Objects of the same **Type** are entered in "loops", e.g. a `for` or a `while` loop.

Object attributes of different **Type** will be entered one after the other.

---

If you have a `struct` or `class` and want to enter all its attributes with a simple extraction (`>>`) operation, then you will observe that the existing extract operator `>>` does not know, how to work with your **Type**. That, because you defined a new **Type**, for example "Player". So we need to tell the compiler how to "Get" the data. And for that, we need to define the input functionality for the new **Type**. This is done with so called operator overloading. Sorry, you need to read about that. But, it is simple for input and for output. Within a `struct` you can normally use the following function signature:

```
struct Player {
    std::string firstName{};
    std::string name {};
    unsigned int age{};
    double score{};

    // Extraction (input)
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Player& p);

    // Insertion (output)
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Player& p);
};
```

You need to program the details of these functions.

So, next, the Team. Here you need many objects of the same **Type**, so many "Players".

You could write `std::vector<Player> team{};` to define a team having many players.

And a complete example for the stuff learned so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

struct Player {
    std::string firstName{};
    std::string name{};
    unsigned int age{};
    double score{};

    // Extraction (input)
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Player& p) {
        std::getline(is >> std::ws, p.firstName);
        std::getline(is, p.name);
        return is >> p.age >> p.score;
    }
    // Insertion (output)
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Player& p) {
        return os << p.firstName << ' ' << p.name << ' ' << p.age << ' ' << p.score;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Define the team
    std::vector<Player> team{};

    // Give user instructions and get number of players for input
    std::cout << "How many players do you want to enter?\n";
    int numberOfPlayers{}; std::cin >> numberOfPlayers;

    // Get the player data and add to team
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        std::cout << "\n\nEnter player data << " << i + 1 << "  One at a line : First name, name, age, score:\n";
        Player player;
        std::cin >> player;
        team.push_back(player);
    }

    // Show complete team:
    std::cout << "\n\nTeam:\n";
    for (const Player& p : team)
        std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Since you did not state your requirements very clearly, I cannot answer further. But you should have understood the basics now and can add further `struct`s and arrays as needed.

Happy coding